# How to copy and paste data in same row number in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to copy and paste the non-blank numbers from value 2 to value 1, but I can't paste on the same row number

[image: Image attached]

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  You may still get additional answers.  If an answer solves the problem for you, consider accepting it (click the checkmark next to it).  That helps other users by identifying that there is a proven solution here, and also awards a little rep to both of you for the effort.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use **Paste Special:**

Copy the data you want, and get ready to paste. But instead of doing a normal paste, select the little button under "Paste" (on the "Home" tab in the ribbon) and select "Paste Special"

Check the box that says **"Skip blanks"**

[image]